# UITableViewHeaderFooterView with xib(nib)

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib, nib

I wrote the source code at the bottom.

I gave `File's Owner` the `IconHeader` class and after connecting the `imageView` as an `IBOutlet`, when I run the application, my application crashes and I get the following error.

[image]

```
Thread 1: "[<NSObject 0x6000030c8860> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key iconImageView."
```

Then I removed `ImageView` from `inpector` and deleted `IconHeader` in `File's Owner` from class and added `IconHeader` to `View`'s class. I chose `Icon Header` from `Object` tab while connecting `ImageView`.

[image]

This time, when I run the application, the following text appears on the console. `"Then I removed ImageView from inpector and deleted IconHeader in File's Owner from class and added IconHeader to View's class. I chose Icon Header from Object tab while connecting ImageView."`

[image]

**MainViewController:**

```
final class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var viewModel: MainViewModelProtocol? {
        didSet {
            viewModel?.delegate = self
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        preapreTableView()
        registerCellsForTableView()
        registerHeaderForTableView()
        viewModel?.fetchAgents()
    }
    
    private func preapreTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    private func registerCellsForTableView() {
        let descriptionCellName = String(describing: DescriptionCell.self)
        let descriptionCellNib = UINib(nibName: descriptionCellName, bundle: .main)
        tableView.register(descriptionCellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: descriptionCellName)
    }
    
    private func registerHeaderForTableView() {
        let iconHeaderName = String(describing: IconHeader.self)
        let iconHeaderNib = UINib(nibName: iconHeaderName, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(iconHeaderNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: iconHeaderName)
    }
}
```

**MainViewController Extension:**

```
extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        guard let section = viewModel?.cellType[section]
        else { return nil }
        if case .description = section {
            guard let iconHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: String(describing: IconHeader.self)) as? IconHeader
            else { return nil }
            return iconHeader
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**IconHeader:**

```
final class IconHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var iconImageView: UIImageView!
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        if let view = loadViewFromNib() {
            view.frame = bounds
            view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            contentView.backgroundColor = .red
            contentView.addSubview(view)
        }
    }
    
    private func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let nibName = String(describing: IconHeader.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're doing more work than needed...

Let's start with changing the `IconHeader` to this:

```
final class IconHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    @IBOutlet var iconImageView: UIImageView!
    
}
```

Next we create a new, Empty User Interface File:

[image]

and save it as `IconHeader` (with default .xib extension).

Add a plain `UIView`:

[image]

and set Simulated Metrics -> Size to Freeform:

[image]

Resize it to make it easy to work with (the size for the moment doesn't matter), and assign **its** class to `IconHeader`:

[image]

Drag in a `UIImageView` ... constrain it centered, at 30x30 ... give it a systemYellow background so we can see its frame, and any image (I used the Swift SF Symbol with Red Tint color) ... and connect the `@IBOutlet`:

[image]

Now let's use a simplified view controller so we can run it without your `viewModel`. We'll use a default `UITableViewCell` class, 10 sections, 2 rows in each section:

```
final class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        preapreTableView()
        registerCellsForTableView()
        registerHeaderForTableView()
    }
    
    private func preapreTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    private func registerCellsForTableView() {
        // register a default cell
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    private func registerHeaderForTableView() {
        let iconHeaderName = String(describing: IconHeader.self)
        let iconHeaderNib = UINib(nibName: iconHeaderName, bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(iconHeaderNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: iconHeaderName)
    }
    
}

extension MainViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return c
    }
    
}

extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        
        guard let iconHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: String(describing: IconHeader.self)) as? IconHeader
        else { return nil }
        return iconHeader
        
    }
    
}
```

Running that, we get:

[image]

Unfortunately, even though we are not setting any background colors, you will see this error / warning message for each section header in the debug console:

```
[TableView] Changing the background color of UITableViewHeaderFooterView 
  is not supported. Use the background view configuration instead.
```

To get rid of that, in your xib, change the view's background color from `System Background` to `Default`:

[image]

No more error messages.

To actually **set** the background color, we can do that either in `viewForHeaderInSection`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    guard let iconHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: String(describing: IconHeader.self)) as? IconHeader
    else { return nil }

    iconHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = .cyan
    
    return iconHeader
    
}
```

Output:

[image]

or, we can set a default color in the `IconHeader` cell class init:

```
final class IconHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    @IBOutlet var iconImageView: UIImageView!
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        contentView.backgroundColor = .green
    }

}
```

[image]